# Why is there a bunch of WordPress HTML code in my browser CSV download?

Tags: plugin-development, headers, csv

I'm trying to add a button/link to an existing WordPress page to allow downloading a dynamically created CSV file. The contents of the CSV file are retrieved from the WordPress database.

Unfortunately the downloaded CSV file contains many lines of HTML code from the page before the actual email list retrieved from the DB.

All code below is located in a plugin that I developed.

This is the function creating the CSV file:

```
function csv_download()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}email_list ORDER BY 'first_name' LIMIT 200";
    $filename = 'EmailList.csv';
    $table_header = array(
        'First Name',
        'Last Name',
        'Address',
        'Email',
    );

    $f = fopen(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/email.csv', 'w');

    fputcsv($f, $table_header);

    $rows = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $csvrow = array($row->first_name, $row->last_name, $row->street_address, $row->email);
        fputcsv($f, $csvrow);
    }

    fclose($f);

    header('Content-Type: text/csv'); // tells browser to download
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // expire date in the past!
    readfile(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/email.csv');
    unlink(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/email.csv');

    exit;
}
```

When I open the email.csv file on the server everything looks good. I temporarily disabled unlink() to do so.

I also created a shortcode to add the button to the page:

```
function email_list_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
{
    ob_start();
    include 'template-parts/email-list.php';
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('email_page', 'email_list_shortcode');
```

This also works. The button shows up and it creates the download when pressed.

This is the content of the include file "email-list.php":

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['CSV']) ) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../assets/helpers.php'; // contains csv_download() function
    csv_download();
}

?>
<form class="float-right" aria-label="CSV Download" method="GET" action="">
     <input type="hidden" name="CSV" value="true">
     <button class="form-button" type="submit">Download CSV</button>
</form>
```

When I click the button it creates the download but there is a problem. The download contains many lines of HTML code from the page before the actual email list starts. It appears that it is the HTML before the button insertion point. And it's a lot of HTML.

I've tried for days now to resolve this problem but to no avail.

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: what you're trying to do requires sending HTTP headers, which means it can never be done inside a shortcode, because shortcodes don't execute until the theme header etc has already been printed. The `csv_download` function will never work from a shortcode, and you can expect to see multiple PHP warnings in your error log that HTTP headers already been sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code cannot run in a shortcode:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['CSV']) ) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../assets/helpers.php'; // contains csv_download() function
    csv_download();
}
```

The problem  is that by the time a shortcode executes it's too late to send HTTP headers, and WordPress has already sent the theme header and HTML body tags. Shortcodes are meant for inserting dynamic content into post content, not this.

That doesn't mean you can't use a shortcode for your form, just that the `csv_download` needs to be called much earlier, *outside* the shortcode.

For example, on the `init` hook:

```php
// if the user has pressed the button
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['CSV']) ) {
    // do the csv download on the 'init' hook/action/event instead of the shortcode
    add_action( 'init', 'bistromatic_generate_csv_download' );
}
function bistromatic_generate_csv_download() {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../assets/helpers.php'; // contains csv_download() function
    csv_download();
}

function email_list_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
{
    ob_start();
    ....... etc
```

This would work because the code runs before any theme templates are loaded. This does mean that the `add_action` call must happen in a plugin or `functions.php`, and it can't be inside another function or a file included at a later point or on a hook. Timing and the order of execution is critical.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your insight!

Comment: I'm currently running in a test environment on my Synology NAS behind a firewall. I plan to use fopen("php://memory", "w") in the production version. The live site does not have any of this code. I'll also add prefixes to distinguish from other plugins. And I will definitely try the init hook!

Comment: Tom, I tried the code you provided using the init hook to initiate the download. Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I've added some tracing to the calls and the add_action function gets executed but the callback bistromatic_generate_csv_download() function never gets executed. :(

Comment: that's odd, I'm assuming the check, the add_action, and the function definition are in the top level of the file, not inside a shortcode/function, and in a plugin/`functions.php` not a theme template. The `add_action` needs to happen _before_ the `init` action fires, it's not just what you do, it's _when_ you do it, the order is significant, so this will never work in a theme template, or a file loaded on the `init` action as it would require the `init` action to happen twice to work

Comment: Thanks again Tom. I figured it out. Had the code in the wrong file!